# Why does selecting one checkbox select all in ember?

Tags: ember.js

can anyone tell me why all checkboxes get selected when one is checked?

I´d like to get the ids of the selected checkboxes.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/poqabavi/2/edit

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is because once you click on a checkbox for the first time, `isChecked` becomes `true`, which updates every checkbox that relies on that variable.

One way to get around this is to set the `isChecked` attribute on the Company model:

```
App.Company = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  people: DS.hasMany('person', {async: true}),
  isChecked: false
});
```

And your checkbox code would be `{{input type="checkbox" checked=company.isChecked}}`.

Then you can easily get which ones are checked by iterating over the content.

[Here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/poqabavi/6/edit?html,css,js,output) is the updated JSbin with my suggestions:

Answer (score 2):

In the current state of your application, all the checkboxes are referring to the same variable, `IndexController.get('isChecked')` and `IndexController.set('isChecked', value)`. If you change that variable's scope from the controller to the individual `Company` models, it will work as desired.

`<td> {{input type="checkbox" checked=company.isChecked}}</td>`

Once that's changed, you can use `var companies = this.content.filterBy('isChecked')` in your `IndexController` to get the companies that have been checked in the form.